# tableau dual axis mapping issue in second layer longitude latitude

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 custom long-lat data sources, one for area polygon, and one for point data as follows:
[area polygon data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNNHC.jpg)

[point data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWZYU.jpg)

I tried to map them on tableau using instructions on https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_dualaxis.htm
, but I cannot get the spread-ed point data on the second layer. all I get is one point.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWBCL.jpg)

Comment: for second chart do you see any unknown locaitons?

Comment: yes It has some data points with NULL vales for long lat columns

Comment: Some times tableau can't identify the points then it won't map those points, So you need to click on that and edit the locations and map as per your requriements

Comment: I tried to map again removing NULL values from the data source file. But came up with the same result

Comment: Not null values edit locations